# Difference between /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyS0 (Arduino IDE ports under Linux)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, usb, communication

I use the Arduino IDE to upload sketches to my Arduino Uno. My OS is Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The Arduino IDE has two ports by default for communication with the Arduino Uno:

```
/dev/ttyACM0
/dev/ttyS0
```

1. What is the difference between these two ports ?
2. What does "ACM0" and "S0" mean ?
3. Are there configuration files somewhere in the OS folder structure that describe the parameters of these ports ?

I know that when I select `/dev/ttyACM0`, I am able to send data to my Arduino Uno. However it does not work when I select `/dev/ttyS0`.

I just want to better understand what these ports are exactly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/dev/ttyACM0` is a USB [communication device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) (CDC) of sub-type "abstract control model" (ACM). That is what the Arduino is.

`/dev/ttyS0` is a hardware serial port - the (typically) 9-pin D connector on the back of your computer.

If you want to use `/dev/ttyS0` (why would you?!) you will require a special cable that converts the RS-232 voltage signals from the 9-pin D connector into the right TTL level signals for the Ardiuno and wire it in to the right pins on the board.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Can You help how to upgrade firmware on Sim800 using Sim 800 Serious tool for Linux as it mentioned `Usage: mtkdownload <com> ROM_VIVA <format>

<com>: /dev/ttyS0,/dev/ttyS1,/dev/ttyS2..
means  COM1,COM2,COM3,COM4,USB2COM
ROM_VIVA is updating rom file
<format> Y,N
means  format FAT or not format Fat
Example: mtkdownload 100 ROM_VIVA Y
` and When I use  `./mtkdownload /dev/ttyACM0 ./ROM_VIVA ` It just print same above.

Answer (score -1):

Some high-level languages (e.g. matlab) treat all serial ports as the  /dev/ttyS# selecter.  To interface with an Arduino with MATLAB you have to rename /dev/ttyACM0 as /dev/ttyS#.

This may also be an option in the Arduino IDE, and that is why those options exist.

Comment: why would you rename it when a symlink could do the trick ?